# `fetch': key not found: "data" (KeyError) : graphql-client error

Tags: ruby, graphql

I was trying to use the graphql query within ruby to fetch github repositories. Before writing the query, I was working on getting the graphql-client working. I'm facing issues with graphql client.

I was following this link for graphql client: 
        https://github.com/github/graphql-client

```
require 'graphql'
require 'graphql/client'
require 'graphql/client/http'

module MyGraphQL
  HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new('https://github.com/graphql') do
    def client_context
      { access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }
    end

    def headers(_context)
      client_context
    end
  end

  Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)

  Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema, execute: HTTP)
end
```

I'm getting the following errors in a terminal:

```
    'fetch': key not found: "data" (KeyError)
    'load'
    'load_schema'
    'load_schema'
```

Answer (score 3):

This error appears due to response you receive via fetching https://github.com/graphql.

You can use `binding.pry` ([this gem](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)), for example, to see what happening, when you try to run `load_schema` method.
It tries to fetch `data` from response here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCTe0.png

But there is no `data` attribute, because you get `{"errors"=>[{"message"=>"422 Unprocessable Entity"}]}`

Try to fetch http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/, for example, worked for me.

Comment: Actually, the current (Jan/2021) SWAPI endpoint is https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index.

Answer (score 2):

Also faced with same problem. Replacing `body` method to this helped:

```
    def headers(context)
      {
        "Authorization" => "bearer #{TOKEN}"
      }
    end
```

Where is the `TOKEN` is the Personal access token gotten from here: https://github.com/settings/tokens